# Push an element at the end of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called **result** which I generate like this

```
 while something
           $result[] = $row;
           array_push($result,$row['fld_ConsumptionValue'] * $energy_type_unit_price) // this won't do 
    endwhile
```

*$result* array is filled with db records. What I wanna do is to push another value I calculated like above. output is like this:

```
    result -> Array[6]
    [0] -> Array[34]
    [1] -> Calculated Value For 1st Record
    [2] -> Array[34]
    [3] -> Calculated Value For 2nd Record
...
...
...
```

What I'm trying is to get this output

```
 result -> Array[6]
    [0] -> Array[35]
    [1] -> Array[35]
...
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do this, instead do it in the simple way:

```
$result[] = $row['fld_ConsumptionValue'] * $energy_type_unit_price;
```

The above will add the value to the end of the array. If you want to use the array `Array[34]`, add that then. Not sure how do you generate that array with 34 items. Or if I get it right, you gotta do this:

```
$row [] = $row['fld_ConsumptionValue'] * $energy_type_unit_price
$result[] = $row;
```

The above adds the new one to the `$row` and you add all the 35 to the main `$result`.

Answer (score 1):

This is it:

```
while something
    // add new key to `$row`
    $row['someKey'] = $row['fld_ConsumptionValue'] * $energy_type_unit_price;
    // add `$row` to `$result`
    $result[] = $row;
endwhile
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do is `$array[] = $var;`

In your case `$result[] = $row['fld_ConsumptionValue'] * $energy_type_unit_price;`

Refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php for details

Hope it helps

Comment: Uh, that's what he does already, but it doesn't work in his case. `:)`